# Set black color as default in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

How to paste color of any text as black in google doc?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V for pasting unformatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, please use "Ctrl+Shift+V for pasting unformatted text".
It works like magic!!!